# Why Installer made with installshield hangs when deployed using ReleaseManagementBuild.exe?

Tags: ms-release-management, installshield-2012

I have a build definition in TFS that compile my code, then using a post build event, I create a Setup.exe file using Installshield.

Using **Release Management** I am able to deploy the installer to a machine and start the installation process using the tool **RunCommandLine**, I add the required parameters to the setup.exe so it will install the application silently (using an answer file to avoid user interaction). This process works smoothly!!!

I want to go far, so I tried to launch a release from a gated check-in....change the build template, install the release management client in the build agent, configure my build definition......I performed a small change in my code, then a check-in.....it compiles in the server, and start the release process: deploy the installer and start the installation process using the tool RunCommandLine, I add the required parameters to the setup.exe so it will install the application silently.....but I got a timeout so the release was rejected. I check the machine and found that the setup.exe was still running 0% CPU usage.....very strange.

Checking the build log I found that the command line used by msbuild to launch the release process is something like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\Client\bin\ReleaseManagementBuild.exe -tfs "http://tfs:8080/tfs/Mycollection" -tp "Project1" -bd "Mybuild" -bn "Mybuild_20150623_15.1.0.9" -ts "QA" -nologo
```

I ran it, and the behavior was the same: the installer got stuck...0% CPU Usage.....Release rejected by timeout.....

So...I open **Release Management Client** look for the recently created release, and click in the option "**Retry failed deployment**"....It works!!!! the installer install!!! it does not hangs!!!

I was able to reproduce this behavior several times:

Release launched from Release Management Console......Works

Release launched from ReleaseManagementBuild.exe .......Does not works (Setup.exe hangs)

Any suggestion??

Comment: Does the issue occur from other releases? Is your build server able to communicate with the RM server?

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, it occur with different releases, and to your other question, the build server is able to communicate with the RM server